# Submitting a new XCode project app as an existing app

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I have a published iOS app and no source code for that app.

Can I remake it from scratch as a new XCode project and publish as an update of the original app?

Comment: It doesn't matter, you can obviously do this, just make it better than before ;-)

Comment: 85% of your posted question is irrelevant to your actual question. Please edit it to only include the actual question and relevant info.

Comment: I have updated the question, hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

**Since the question was updated my answer does not fit exactly anymore, will leave it there anyway.**

**Original Question was something like:**

*My friend created and submitted an app but lost his source code somehow. I wanted to buy it from him and wondered if I can create a new project, re-code the app from scratch and upload the binary as update.*

**This was my answer:**

You should do the following:

1. create your own developer account with distribution rights
2. make him transfer the app to your developer account in iTunesConnect
3. create the app code so you can update it
4. update the app
5. do whatever you want to do

hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer hinges on your definition of "existing app". Each app has an app ID, and various information (such as sales history, ratings, reviews) are attached to that app ID.

If you define "existing app" as functionality and name, you can get the source code, create a new app ID, and submit the app as your own.

If you define "existing app" as seamlessly updating existing users with new/fixed functionality (what I would consider the normal definition of "existing app") then your friend will need to transfer the app to you via iTunes Connect. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html

If you're using existing source/project files, it'll be smoother, but if you're recreating the project, make sure you use the existing app ID/bundle ID.

Comment: Yes, he'll be transferring the app through iTunes connect. I just wondered if after the transfer is complete I can just upload a new binary from a completely new Xcode project. I guess the answer is yes. Thanks!

Comment: Just make sure you use the same appID/bundleID in the new project. (And added this to the answer.)